# How to change the color of one factor in every dataset in a list using a loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of 6 datasets, each of which has one factor named "unique" that I would like to set as the same color within all my datasets, while leaving all my other factors intact with the same colors

As an example, I currently have something along these lines:

```
allPlots<-list()
for(i in seq(length(allData))){
allPlots[[i]]<-ggplot(allData[[i]], aes(y=count, x="", fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend=FALSE,fill = c(rev(hue_pal()(1)),"black"))+
  ggtitle(names(allData)[i])

  
}
```

Within each of my datasets, I ordered it so that my factor level of note, "unique", is the first row in all my datasets, hence the rev(hue_pal()(**1**)) call. However, upon attempting to plot all of these plots, I get the error code "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (35): fill"

Thanks !

Comment: Your vector of colors should have the same length as your dataset (that's basically what the error says). Not sure what is Category here. But I usually do this with something like aes(y=count, x="", color=mycolors) where mycolors is the name of the column in your dataframe that represent (assign) the colors (as characters).